# Why does Visual Studio place a div tag in a new ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

By default, a new ASPX page contains the following:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm curious--is there any reason I should leave that div tag in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no real point, but I don't think it's standards-compliant to write text straight after a `<form>` tag, but it would be inside a `<div>`. Feel free to delete it though.

Answer (score 4):

To put things in it? It's not necessary, but it prevents you from having to create a div tag when starting out your web layout.

Comment: It also might go back to the days when they wanted developing web sites to be like windows forms.  Where you would *shudders* drag and drop the controls on a page.

Comment: @Longhorn213 - that would be my suspicion as I know of people who still drag and drop their interface then position everything absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because said DIV is part of the template. No, it doesn't matter and you can feel free to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they are subtly encouraging designers to shed the [`<TABLE>` mentality and move to `<DIV>s`](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/websites-tables-parts-1-2/). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like it, you can always edit the default template to remove them permanently:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Web\WebNewFileItems\CSharp\WebForm.aspx
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Web\WebNewFileItems\VB\WebForm.aspx

Just remove the <div> </div> tags from the relevant one of these for your projects.